# Android 5 - Redirect stdout to logcat

Tags: android, stdout, logcat, googletest, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to run some GMock/GTest tests on Android. These all run fine, but there's no output, as GMock logs to stdout.

I've tried the following with no luck (likely because it's for the [Dalvik VM](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#viewingStd), and they've done away with that in Android 5):

```
$ adb shell stop
$ adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true
$ adb shell start
```

When `log.redirect-stdio` is set to true, there is still no output from stdio to logcat.

I've also tried custom several `streambuf` implementations with `std::cout.rdbuf` to try to direct stdout to logcat with `__android_log_print`, but none of these have printed anything to logcat.

Has anyone successfully managed to redirect stdout to logcat in Android 5?

I can add more details (such as `streambuf` implementations I've tried) if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a solution to the problem of redirecting stdout to logcat, but I'm suggesting it as a workaround in case it helps someone.

You can redirect stdout to a file instead:

```
freopen("/data/data/com.your.package/files/out.txt", "w", stdout);
... // Call GMock which prints to the file instead
fclose(stdout)
```

We can then `cat` the file to see the logged test results. Sadly Android doesn't have `tail` so the logging isn't nicely available in real time. (Unless you're good at spamming `cat`)

Comment: If you actually want it in logcat, you can do that by pointing it at a pipe that you read and proxy to the log in another thread/process, much like the old functionality used to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Do it with the old Java way:** (but I am using kotlin, can anyone suggest a cleaner version?)

[documentation: System.setOut()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream))

```
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.io.PrintStream

private const val TAG = "MyActivity"
class LogcatOutputStream: OutputStream(){
    private var line_buffer: StringBuilder = StringBuilder()
    override fun write(b: Int){
        when(b){
            '\n'.toInt() -> {
                Log.i(TAG, line_buffer.toString())
                line_buffer.setLength(0)
            }
            else -> line_buffer.append(b.toChar())
        }
    }
}

// put this somewhere in the code, like onCreate() as shown
class MainActivity: Activity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        // some other code

        PrintStream(LoggerOutputStream()).let{
            System.setOut(it)
            System.setErr(it)
        }

        // some other code
    }
}

// result:
println("Hello World") // which is effectively System.out.println in Java
// with have the below output in logcat
I/MyActivity(<pid>): Hello World
// as a reminder, you can filter logcat by tags
adb logcat MyActivity:D
// to only show logs tagged with 'MyActivity' (same value as 'TAG' above)
```